# preprocess js before browserify

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

How can I setup a gulp-replace task so that it would modify a js file before browserify? I need to somehow pipe it into it, but struggling with the api. I also don't want to use browserify transformers (ex: preprocessify) because i only need to do replacing on a single file (env properties), not the entire bundle.

```
gulp.task('js', function() { 
// run gulp-replace here
var b =  browserify(entryPoint) 
  .bundle() 
  .pipe(source('bundle.js')) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/'));
```

Comment: looks like that transformer is using a very simple browserify-transform-tools that i can understand. I suppose I can mess around with that itself to make it configurable to work on only the files i need.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this browserify transform after all - [preprocessify](https://github.com/evanmuller/preprocessify). There isn't an easy way to limit the files to a unique set, only by file extensions. The transform uses [preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess) library, which gets me enough features to address my use-cases.

**Here's what preprocessify does:**

```
var transformTools = require('browserify-transform-tools');
var pp = require('preprocess');

module.exports = function(preprocessContext, options) {
  options = options || {includeExtensions: [".js"]};
  return transformTools.makeStringTransform("preprocessify", options,
        function (src, transformOptions, done) {
            done(null, pp.preprocess(src, preprocessContext, 'js'));
        });
};
```